# Visual Studio - Can't run program: the .exe can't be found

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a program and so far, it was working perfectly well but now I have a problem: when I build my project, it works, it generates the .exe but I can't run it, I get this error:

Unable to start program 'H:\C++\Shooter\Debug\Shooter.exe'. Specified file could not be     found

(it's a translation)

When I look in the Debug folder, the exe is here and when I try to execute it manually, it throws the same error and deletes the .exe. Note that everything works on my second computer which has the same version of Visual Studio.

Also, this project shares the same solution than an other one (the server) but the server works fine.

I already tried repairing Visual Studio but it didn't solve my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have a virus infection, and your antivirus software deletes the infected file? maybe you can check for a logfile.

Comment: Did you copy the project from  the other computer to yours via a network share or something,  maybe check the properties of the exe file is it is not blocked...

Comment: I am pretty sure that it's not a virus because I ran several scans and it didn't detect anything (and why would a virus target this file ?). The project is on my USB key but the linkers of the two Visual Studios are configured so that I just have to plug my USB Stick in, but I didn't change anything in the linker settings.

Comment: I had the exact same problem with VS 2012 and VS 2010. For the problem with VS 2010, I had to go back to setup (control panel and uninstall/repair) and select repair. For VS 2012, I had to add VS projects directory to my anti-virus "safe zone" (I added the root projects location) and the problem went away. It is simply the anti-virus being "over cautious" - nothing to do with viruses, per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my antivirus that was causing the problem so I put the directory to my anti-virus safe zone.